# Why is the return type of `myOverloadedFunction(foo as any)` different from `ReturnType<typeof myOverloadedFunction>`?

Tags: typescript, overloading, type-inference, any

I have a simple overloaded function like this:

```
function myFunction(input: string): string
function myFunction(input: undefined): undefined
function myFunction(input: string | undefined): string | undefined
function myFunction(input: string | undefined): string | undefined {
    return input
}
```

This function works as expected with properly typed input:

```
const result1 = myFunction('foo') // Inferred type of result1: string
const result2 = myFunction(undefined) // Inferred type of result2: undefined
const input3: string | undefined = 'foo'
const result3 = myFunction(input3) // Inferred type of result3: string | undefined
```

However, when `input` is typed as `any`, the compiler assumes that the first overload is being used, even though an `any` can be `undefined`:

```
const result4 = myFunction(undefined as any) // Inferred type of result4: string
```

This is surprising to me (and incorrect!). I would expect `result4` to be inferred as `ReturnType<typeof myFunction>` (which is `string | undefined`) instead.

What's going on here? What's the motivation for this behavior?

Comment: What happens if you change the order in which you define the overloads? Is the same one still called?

My guess would be that the first one to be defined will always be the one that will be called because the compiler is presumably checking which of the overloads accepts a parameter of type 'any'. Since they all do, it would default to the first one in the list. Personally, I would consider this to be the expected behavior since type assertion basically amounts to telling the compiler "Trust me, despite what you may think, I know that this object is of this type"

Comment: @Searnd sorry for the late reply, I forgot about this. If you move the `string | undefined` overload to the top, then TS will *always* select that overload, even if `input` is known to be just `string` or just `undefined`. So it works with `any`, but breaks the non-`any` cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon [this trick](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/blob/5562cfaaa04bbcea141c553dbdb211fec8224357/src/reactjs/tests/utils.tsx#L81) from the `react-query` codebase, and adapted it into an `any`-safe solution to this question:

```
type NonOptional<T> = Exclude<T, undefined | null>

// Needs a better name than SafeMap, I'm open to suggestions
type SafeMap<TIn, TOut> = 0 extends 1 & TIn
  ? TOut | undefined
  : TIn extends NonOptional<TIn>
  ? NonOptional<TOut>
  : TIn extends undefined
  ? undefined
  : TOut | undefined;

function parseDate<T extends string | undefined>(arg: T): SafeMap<T, Date> {
  // Fake implementation to satisfy the compiler for the sake of this example
  return undefined as unknown as SafeMap<T, Date>
}

const anyArg: any = undefined
const stringArg: string = ''
const undefinedArg: undefined = undefined
const stringOrUndefinedArg: string | undefined = ''

const anyResult = parseDate(anyArg) // inferred type: `Date | undefined`
const stringResult = parseDate(stringArg) // inferred type: `Date`
const undefinedResult = parseDate(undefinedArg) // inferred type: `undefined`
const stringOrUndefinedResult = parseDate(stringOrUndefinedArg) // inferred type: `Date | undefined`
const _ = parseDate(42) // compilation error because 42 is not assignable to `string | undefined`
```

This works because `any` violates the normal rules of types--you might expect `1 & any` to be `1`, but it's actually `any`. So `0` extends `1 & any`, but not `1 & AnyTypeOtherThanAny`.